# TYPO3 Empty Characters in Rich-Text-Editor (htmlarea) in new Data records from tx_news

Tags: typo3, rich-text-editor, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I've made an update from `TYPO3 6.2`to `TYPO3 7.6`. Now I insert a new `tx_news`-data record -> insert only headline and some other required fields -> save & close.

In preview (frontend) I see my entries but also 'empty characters' in some other textfields (`htmlarea`richt-text-editor). In my case 'Teilnahmemodalitäten'. The field is prefill with 2 characters. You'll see it if you're insert `<f:debug>{newsItem.eventParticipationModalities}</f:debug>`, see screenshot:
[image: prefill with 2 chars inside the rich text editor]

And here you can see it in Backend. The cursor is is on line 3:
[image: rte not empty]

I've made a condition, because I don't want to show the headline, if the field is empty .. **but why my textfield isn't empty by default?**

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.eventParticipationModalities}">
  <div class="press-info">
    <h3>Teilnahmemodalitäten</h3>
    <f:format.raw>{newsItem.eventParticipationModalities}</f:format.raw>
    </div>
</f:if>
```

This field 'Teilnahmemodalitärten' is a extra field for `tx_news`. Here's my `ext_tables.php`:

```
'event_participation_modalities' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:.../locallang.xlf:news.event_participation_modalities',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'enableRichtext' => true,
    ),
    'defaultExtras' => 'richtext'
),
```

and ext_tables.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE tx_news_domain_model_news (
  ...
  event_participation_modalities text NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

I haven't the problem with `TYPO3 6.2`... what can I do? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [VHS:TrimViewhelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Format/TrimViewHelper.html) to trim your value, like this:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<f:if condition="{newsItem.eventParticipationModalities -> v:format.trim()}">
  <div class="press-info">
    <h3>Teilnahmemodalitäten</h3>
    <f:format.raw>{newsItem.eventParticipationModalities}</f:format.raw>
    </div>
</f:if>
```

Comment: Hello Mario. Thanks for your post. I'll test your answer later, but I think that could be the solution. But you also don't know, why the RTE have 2 chars already inside?
 https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Format/TrimViewHelper.html

Comment: Hallo, I'm sorry, but I also don't know it.